# My changes on PHPunit enviroment variables are not being applied. What can I do?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

So... I'm with a problem: I'm trying to run unit tests on a project that already had a phpunit.xml with some environment variables set, but I want to change them. But when I change them my changes are not applied.

As you can see "DB_CONNECTION" is set to "core_configs" but before it was set to "site". And when I run my tests the config read is "site". I also checked my .env file, it doesn't have any "site" config there. Actually, it is also "core_configs".

Any ideas?

I'm running the project on docker, if it can help

PHPUnit version: 4.8
PHP version: 7.1
Laravel version: 5.2

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="core_configs"/>
        <env name="TESTING_DATABASE" value="imovel_test"/>
        <env name="TESTING_USERNAME" value="homestead"/>
        <env name="TESTING_PASSWORD" value="secret"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**EDIT:**

And no, the default 'site' is not being used because I have a DB_CONNECTION on my .env. And I also tried changing it

config/database

```php
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'site'),
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('SQLLITE_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'site' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SITE', 'mysql'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SITE', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SITE', 'u1915_ssc_1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SITE', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SITE', 'example'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'install' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('INSTALL_DB_HOST_CORECONFIG', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SPANEL', '3308'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'api_core'),
            'username' => env('INSTALL_DB_USERNAME_CORECONFIG', ''),
            'password' => env('INSTALL_DB_PASSWORD_CORECONFIG', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'spanel' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SPANEL', 'mysql'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SPANEL', '3308'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SPANEL', 'u1915_ssc_1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SPANEL', 'local_user'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SPANEL', 'example'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'core_configs' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_CORECONFIG', 'mysql'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_CORECONFIG', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_CORECONFIG', 'api_core'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_CORECONFIG', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_CORECONFIG', 'example'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: share the content of the file `config/database.php`

Comment: sure, i shared it